# Network Manager killing vpn connection

Tags: linux-mint, openvpn, networkmanager

I will start by providing some info:

```
System:    Host: arthur-desktop Kernel: 4.10.0-38-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.6.7 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) Distro: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Machine:   System: Dell product: OptiPlex 9010 v: 01
           Mobo: Dell model: 00F82W v: A00 Bios: Dell v: A14 date: 06/11/2013
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-3770 (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 27139
           clock speeds: max: 3900 MHz 1: 1675 MHz 2: 1684 MHz 3: 1619 MHz 4: 1697 MHz 5: 1686 MHz 6: 1646 MHz
           7: 1674 MHz 8: 1665 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GK107 [GeForce GT 640 OEM] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 2560x1440@59.95hz, 2560x1440@59.95hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GT 640/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.130 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 7 Series/C210 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 NVIDIA GK107 HDMI Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
           Card-3 Plantronics driver: USB Audio usb-ID: 001-008
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-38-generic
Network:   Card: Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: f040 bus-ID: 00:19.0
           IF: eno1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (2.5% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD10EZEX size: 1000.2GB
           Optical: /dev/sr0 model: PLDS DVD+-RW DH-16AES rev: 3D11 dev-links: cdrom,cdrw,dvd,dvdrw
           Features: speed: 48x multisession: yes
           audio: yes dvd: yes rw: cd-r,cd-rw,dvd-r,dvd-ram state: running
Partition: ID-1: / size: 468G used: 8.4G (2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 17.13GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C gpu: 0.0:47C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 325 Uptime: 3 days Memory: 10238.3/16000.0MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35

 Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 047f:013c Plantronics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:4d51 Primax Electronics, Ltd 0Y357C PMX-MMOCZUL (B) [Dell Laser Mouse]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Ive installed and configured the priunl vpn client same as i did on my other Ubuntu 16.04 machine. About 15 seconds after i make a connection it gets killed and I cannot figure out why.

syslog shows the interface being removed by ntpd

```
Jun 19 13:25:08 arthur-desktop ntpd[21679]: Listen normally on 8 tun0 X.X.X.X:123
Jun 19 13:25:08 arthur-desktop ntpd[21679]: Listen normally on 9 tun0 [fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%11]:123
Jun 19 13:25:08 arthur-desktop ntpd[21679]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Jun 19 13:25:36 arthur-desktop ntpd[21679]: Deleting interface #8 tun0, X.X.X.X#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=28 secs
Jun 19 13:25:36 arthur-desktop ntpd[21679]: Deleting interface #9 tun0, fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%11#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=28 secs
```

pritunl log

```
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]X.X.X.X:17978
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 VERIFY SCRIPT OK: depth=1, O=5a9f42f0f8c9296d9593ab8d, CN=5a9f42f0f8c9296d9593ab91
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 VERIFY OK: depth=1, O=5a9f42f0f8c9296d9593ab8d, CN=5a9f42f0f8c9296d9593ab91
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 Validating certificate key usage
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 NOTE: --mute triggered...
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 12 variation(s) on previous 3 message(s) suppressed by --mute
Tue Jun 19 13:25:05 2018 [5a9f46e6f8c9296d9593ae66] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]X.X.X.X:17978
Tue Jun 19 13:25:07 2018 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Tue Jun 19 13:25:07 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Jun 19 13:25:07 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Tue Jun 19 13:25:07 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 X.X.X.X/24 broadcast X.X.X.X
Tue Jun 19 13:25:07 2018 /usr/share/pritunl_client/update-resolv-conf.sh tun0 1500 1602 X.X.X.X 255.255.255.0 init
dhcp-option DNS X.X.X.X
dhcp-option DNS X.X.X.X
Tue Jun 19 13:25:09 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
Tue Jun 19 13:25:35 2018 event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
Tue Jun 19 13:25:35 2018 /bin/true tun0 1500 1602 X.X.X.X 255.255.255.0 init
Tue Jun 19 13:25:35 2018 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Tue Jun 19 13:25:35 2018 /sbin/ip addr del dev tun0 X.X.X.X/24
Tue Jun 19 13:25:35 2018 /usr/share/pritunl_client/update-resolv-conf.sh tun0 1500 1602 X.X.X.X 255.255.255.0 init
Tue Jun 19 13:25:35 2018 SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
```

So far I have tried:

- marking tun0 interface as unmanaged in network-manager configuration
- stopping network-manager
- forcing ntpd to ignore virtual interfaces by adding the -L parameter

So far nothing worked.

**UPDATE**
Removing network-manager completely breaks cinnamon so this is not an option, however I increased the log level for NM to DEBUG

```
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop dbus[914]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop dbus[914]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: DEVICE_IP_IFACE=tun0
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: DEVICE_IFACE=tun0
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_ID=tun0
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_UUID=527193a9-80c4-4307-9b0b-4d2af3749af2
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_EXTERNAL=1
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_DBUS_PATH=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/0
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown": run script
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown": complete
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: completed (1 scripts)
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.6901] dispatcher: (4) 01ifupdown succeeded
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.6903] device[0x16d7dd0] (tun0): emit RECHECK_ASSUME signal
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.6905] device[0x16d7dd0] (tun0): add_pending_action (1): 'autoactivate'
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.6906] active-connection[0x1710100]: disposing
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.6907] manager: assumed connection disconnected. Deleting generated connection 'tun0' (527193a9-80c4-4307-9b0b-4d2af3749af2)
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.6910] Deleting secrets for connection /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/0 (tun0)
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.6911] agent-manager: req[0x16bb090, :1.61/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent allowed for secrets request [0x170f4f0/"tun0"del]
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7340] settings-connection[0x163cb70,527193a9-80c4-4307-9b0b-4d2af3749af2]: disposing
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7347] device[0x16d7dd0] (tun0): remove_pending_action (0): 'autoactivate'
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7348] agent-manager: req[0x16bb090, :1.61/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent deleting secrets for request [0x170f4f0/"tun0"del]
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7351] manager: (tun0): removing device (allow_unmanage 1, managed 0)
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7353] device[0x16d7dd0] (tun0): disposing
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7353] device[0x16d7dd0] (tun0): remove_pending_action (0): 'dhcp6' not pending (expected)
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7353] device[0x16d7dd0] (tun0): remove_pending_action (0): 'autoconf6' not pending (expected)
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7353] device[0x16d7dd0] (tun0): ip4-config: update (commit=1, routes-full-sync=1, new-config=(nil))
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7353] device[0x16d7dd0] (tun0): ip6-config: update (commit=1, routes-full-sync=1, new-config=(nil))
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7353] device[0x16d7dd0] (tun0): finalize(): NMDeviceTun
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7355] default-route: resync: sync now (401) (IPv4 changes: yes, IPv6 changes: yes)
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop NetworkManager[5390]: <debug> [1529487650.7387] agent-manager: req[0x16bb090, :1.61/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent deleted secrets for request [0x170f4f0/"tun0"del]
```

and debug log

```
Jun 20 11:39:55 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'hostname': environment: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Jun 20 11:39:55 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'hostname', "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown": run script
Jun 20 11:39:55 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'hostname', "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown": complete
Jun 20 11:39:55 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'hostname': completed (1 scripts)
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: IP6_GATEWAY=::
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: IP6_NUM_ADDRESSES=1
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: IP6_ADDRESS_0=fe80::e314:3326:2e7c:84bf/64 ::
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: IP4_NUM_ROUTES=0
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: IP4_GATEWAY=0.0.0.0
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: IP4_NUM_ADDRESSES=1
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: IP4_ADDRESS_0=192.168.248.23/24 0.0.0.0
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: DEVICE_IP_IFACE=tun0
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: DEVICE_IFACE=tun0
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_ID=tun0
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_UUID=527193a9-80c4-4307-9b0b-4d2af3749af2
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_EXTERNAL=1
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_DBUS_PATH=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/0
Jun 20 11:40:22 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown": run script
Jun 20 11:40:23 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown": complete
Jun 20 11:40:23 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: completed (1 scripts)
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: DEVICE_IP_IFACE=tun0
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: DEVICE_IFACE=tun0
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_ID=tun0
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_UUID=527193a9-80c4-4307-9b0b-4d2af3749af2
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_EXTERNAL=1
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: environment: CONNECTION_DBUS_PATH=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/0
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown": run script
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown": complete
Jun 20 11:40:50 arthur-desktop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [tun0]: completed (1 scripts)
```

Comment: Tunnel starts up, but after 25 seconds, you get an interrupted system call (timeout?), followed by a SIGTERM (possibly as consequence). So the question is where this interrupted system call comes from, and what exactly is causing it. If you can run the priunl OpenVPN client somehow with more verbose logging enabled, that would help. If ntpd is interfering for some reason, stopping ntpd and trying without it is the obvious experiment.

Comment: By the looks of it it is network-manager thats stopping it. I cannot rmeove network manager because cinnamon depends on it

Comment: I have battled with network manager before, and lost, which is why I've removed network manager from my system. Though I hear it's not as bad as it was when I had to make this decision. Sorry, can't help you here. Possibly you can configure network manager to leave all tun/tap interfaces alone.

Comment: Yes unfortunately Cinnamon relies on Network Manager, which means i cannot remove it. I tried but it breaks the desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a solution to the problem i managed to get the VPN working using the native openvpn client and profile from the provider

It seems that Network Manager is only not liking the connection made by the Pritunl client